# Convert XML to DataTable according to two attributes using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file and I want to make a `DataTable` and bind it to a `GridView`, but the data must be taken from the XML file according to attributes, not the tag. The first attribute is "m" and it represents the row index. The other attribute is "s" and it represents the column index. 
If the attribute isn't mentioned in some tags, the default value for it is "1"

The output must be shown in `GridView` like this form

```
 <asp:GridView id="grdBank" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" >
    <Columns>

      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Repay date" DataField="repay">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>                
      </asp:BoundField>

      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Interest" DataField="interest">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>                
      </asp:BoundField>

      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Penalty interest" DataField="penalty_interest">
         <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>               
      </asp:BoundField>

      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Penalty spread" DataField="penalty_spread">
         <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>               
      </asp:BoundField>

      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Others (CE+CS)" DataField="others">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>                
      </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
```

the xml file is

```
<row>
<c24>20160201</c24>
<c24 m="2">20160131</c24>
<c24 m="3">20160101</c24>
<c24 m="4">20151231</c24>
<c24 m="5">20151201</c24>
<c24 m="6">20151130</c24>
<c24 m="7">20151102</c24>
</row>



<row>
<c28>IN</c28>
<c28 m="1" s="2">PE</c28>
<c28 m="1" s="3">PS</c28>

<c28 m="2">PR</c28>
<c28 m="2" s="2">PE</c28>
<c28 m="2" s="3">PS</c28>

<c28 m="3">IN</c28>
<c28 m="3" s="2">PE</c28>
<c28 m="3" s="3">PS</c28>
<c28 m="3" s="4">CE</c28>
<c28 m="3" s="5">CS</c28>

<c28 m="4">PR</c28>
<c28 m="4" s="2">PE</c28>
<c28 m="4" s="3">PS</c28>
<c28 m="4" s="4">CE</c28>
<c28 m="4" s="5">CS</c28>

<c28 m="5">IN</c28>
<c28 m="5" s="2">PE</c28>
<c28 m="5" s="3">PS</c28>
<c28 m="5" s="4">CE</c28>
<c28 m="5" s="5">CS</c28>

<c28 m="6">PR</c28>
<c28 m="6" s="2">PE</c28>
<c28 m="6" s="3">PS</c28>
<c28 m="6" s="4">CE</c28>
<c28 m="6" s="5">CS</c28>

<c28 m="7">PR</c28>
<c28 m="7" s="2">PE</c28>
<c28 m="7" s="3">PS</c28>
<c28 m="7" s="4">CE</c28>
<c28 m="7" s="5">CS</c28>
</row>




<row>
<c29>1334.564</c29>
<c29 m="1" s="2">9.509</c29>
<c29 m="1" s="3">3.003</c29>

<c29 m="2">3900</c29>
<c29 m="2" s="2">28.817</c29>
<c29 m="2" s="3">9.1</c29>

<c29 m="3">1366.468</c29>
<c29 m="3" s="2">10.097</c29>
<c29 m="3" s="3">3.189</c29>
<c29 m="3" s="4">10.818</c29>
<c29 m="3" s="5">3.416</c29>

<c29 m="4">3900</c29>
<c29 m="4" s="2">28.817</c29>
<c29 m="4" s="3">9.1</c29>
<c29 m="4" s="4">31.904</c29>
<c29 m="4" s="5">10.075</c29>

<c29 m="5">1353.571</c29>
<c29 m="5" s="2">10.001</c29>
<c29 m="5" s="3">3.159</c29>
<c29 m="5" s="4">21.789</c29>
<c29 m="5" s="5">6.881</c29>

<c29 m="6">3900</c29>
<c29 m="6" s="2">28.817</c29>
<c29 m="6" s="3">9.1</c29>
<c29 m="6" s="4">63.808</c29>
<c29 m="6" s="5">20.15</c29>

<c29 m="7">1290.211</c29>
<c29 m="7" s="2">9.533</c29>
<c29 m="7" s="3">3.011</c29>
<c29 m="7" s="4">30.641</c29>
<c29 m="7" s="5">9.678</c29>
</row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string xml =
            "<Root>" +
               "<row>" +
               "<c24>20160201</c24>" +
               "<c24 m=\"2\">20160131</c24>" +
               "<c24 m=\"3\">20160101</c24>" +
               "<c24 m=\"4\">20151231</c24>" +
               "<c24 m=\"5\">20151201</c24>" +
               "<c24 m=\"6\">20151130</c24>" +
               "<c24 m=\"7\">20151102</c24>" +
               "</row>" +

               "<row>" +
               "<c28>IN</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"1\" s=\"2\">PE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"1\" s=\"3\">PS</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"2\">PR</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"2\" s=\"2\">PE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"2\" s=\"3\">PS</c28>" +

               "<c28 m=\"3\">IN</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"3\" s=\"2\">PE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"3\" s=\"3\">PS</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"3\" s=\"4\">CE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"3\" s=\"5\">CS</c28>" +

               "<c28 m=\"4\">PR</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"4\" s=\"2\">PE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"4\" s=\"3\">PS</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"4\" s=\"4\">CE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"4\" s=\"5\">CS</c28>" +

               "<c28 m=\"5\">IN</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"5\" s=\"2\">PE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"5\" s=\"3\">PS</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"5\" s=\"4\">CE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"5\" s=\"5\">CS</c28>" +

               "<c28 m=\"6\">PR</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"6\" s=\"2\">PE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"6\" s=\"3\">PS</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"6\" s=\"4\">CE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"6\" s=\"5\">CS</c28>" +

               "<c28 m=\"7\">PR</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"7\" s=\"2\">PE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"7\" s=\"3\">PS</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"7\" s=\"4\">CE</c28>" +
               "<c28 m=\"7\" s=\"5\">CS</c28>" +
               "</row>" +

               "<row>" +
               "<c29>1334.564</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"1\" s=\"2\">9.509</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"1\" s=\"3\">3.003</c29>" +

               "<c29 m=\"2\">3900</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"2\" s=\"2\">28.817</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"2\" s=\"3\">9.1</c29>" +

               "<c29 m=\"3\">1366.468</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"3\" s=\"2\">10.097</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"3\" s=\"3\">3.189</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"3\" s=\"4\">10.818</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"3\" s=\"5\">3.416</c29>" +

               "<c29 m=\"4\">3900</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"4\" s=\"2\">28.817</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"4\" s=\"3\">9.1</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"4\" s=\"4\">31.904</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"4\" s=\"5\">10.075</c29>" +

               "<c29 m=\"5\">1353.571</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"5\" s=\"2\">10.001</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"5\" s=\"3\">3.159</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"5\" s=\"4\">21.789</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"5\" s=\"5\">6.881</c29>" +

               "<c29 m=\"6\">3900</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"6\" s=\"2\">28.817</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"6\" s=\"3\">9.1</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"6\" s=\"4\">63.808</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"6\" s=\"5\">20.15</c29>" +

               "<c29 m=\"7\">1290.211</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"7\" s=\"2\">9.533</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"7\" s=\"3\">3.011</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"7\" s=\"4\">30.641</c29>" +
               "<c29 m=\"7\" s=\"5\">9.678</c29>" +
               "</row>" +
               "</Root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(m => (m.Name.LocalName != "row") && (m.Name.LocalName != "Root"))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName)
                .Select(y => new
                {
                    name = y.Where(z => z.Attribute("m") == null).Select(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                    months = y.Where(z => z.Attribute("m") != null).GroupBy(z => z.Attribute("m")).Select(a => new
                    {
                        month = (int)a.Key,
                        section = a.Select(b => new
                        {
                            s = b.Attribute("s") == null ? null : (int?)b.Attribute("s"),
                            value = b.Value
                        }).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            foreach (var name in results.AsEnumerable())
            {
                foreach (var month in name.months.AsEnumerable())
                {

                    if (month.section.s == null)
                    {
                        DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { name.name, month.month, 1, month.section.value });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { name.name, month.month, month.section.s, month.section.value });
                    }

                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: another thing :
the data doesn't filled correctly in the dattable
i want the dates shown in column named repay date,
the elements "IN" shown in interest column
"PE" shown in penalty interest
"PS" in penalty spread column
"cs" and "ce" in others column